# passing an element name using a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, openargs

I have a multi page element on a MS Access form and I am trying to use GetArgs to identify which page to open using the below code. Could anyone assist me with how to convert the page name to a format MS Access will accept?

```
Dim WrdArray() As String
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    LoadAndLocation = Me.OpenArgs
    WrdArray() = Split(LoadAndLocation, "|")
    OriginalPage = WrdArray(1) 'This works and results in the correct page name eg Fina
    Me.OriginalPage.SetFocus 
End If
```

Comment: What is a multi page element? Do you mean a tab control with more than one tab? What are you passing into your OpenArgs now? What's wrong with this code? It appears to work fine.

Comment: You are right HK1, it is a tab control with several tabs. I am opening the form that has the tab and the OpenArgs values has a string that is a combination of the tab to be selected and a value to be actioned eg Final|9. After the split The variable OriginalPage is holding the name of the tab that should be selected; in this case the tab named Final. MS Access is giving a Compile error: Method or data member not found and pointing to the line 'Me.OriginalPage.SetFocus'

Comment: @HansUp any possibility you could help out with this?

Comment: I just read Tim Williams' answer and it looks promising to me.  I didn't get a notice about your comment, so didn't see it till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that familiar with Access, so there's maybe a cleaner way to do it, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
Private Sub Tester()

    SetTabByName Me.TabCtl0, "Second" 'set by Caption

    SetTabByName Me.TabCtl0, "Page1"  'set by Name

End Sub


'Set tab control active page: match on tab name *or* caption...
Sub SetTabByName(tabCtrl As TabControl, sVal As String)
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 0 To tabCtrl.Pages.Count - 1
        If tabCtrl.Pages(x).Name = sVal Or _
           tabCtrl.Pages(x).Caption = sVal Then
            tabCtrl.Value = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, was putting in your solution then I realised from your solution I needed to refer to the tab control BEFORE I refer to the page I wanted.
I have added the line 
Dim OriginalPage as String and replaced Me.OriginalPage.SetFocus with Me.tabDeposits.Pages(OriginalPage).SetFocus and it has ran immediately. 
Thank you very much.